# Updating User when submitting form

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

The scenario is that I'm building an app for users to submit payment and gain or renew "Member" status to the site. If an anonymous person wants to create an account all that's required is an email and a password but for membership we're going to want the User.firstname and User.lastname to be filled in as well. I'm not sure how best to incorporate this requirement in the "enrolment" form. Any guidance on approach or best practices welcome.

Here is the code I'm working with

```
class MembershipType(models.Model):
    """The represents the type of membership that may be offered."""

    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    long_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    period = models.PositiveIntegerField()  # The number of days the membership is good for
    accounts = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()  # The number of accounts that it supports
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5,
                                decimal_places=2)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.long_name


class Membership(models.Model):

    """Represents an active membership of a user. Both the start_date and
    end_date parameters are inclusive."""

    DEFAULT_DURATION = 365  # the default number of days a membership is active

    start_date = models.DateField(auto_created=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    membership_type = models.ForeignKey(MembershipType)
    referral = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='membership_referral')

    # Contact Info
    phone = PhoneNumberField()

    # Address Fields
    address_1 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    address_2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)

    city = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    state = USStateField()
    zip_code = USPostalCodeField()

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return self.end_date >= datetime.date.today()


class MembershipUser(models.Model):
    """Simple relationship that associates a single user to a membership object"""
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    membership = models.ForeignKey(Membership)

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None,
             update_fields=None):
        if (self.membership.membership_type.accounts ==
                MembershipUser.objects.filter(membership=self.membership).count()):
            raise NotImplementedError("The Membership %s, already has it's "
                                      "maximum number of accounts associated "
                                      "with it." % self.membership.id)
```

Also, as you may see from that code I have to support to idea of a single user purchasing membership that may be used for for than one user. A use case here is a "Couple's" membership.

Answer (score 0):

The way I implemented it is this. It seems to handle everything jsut fine and will prepoluate the user's info. I feel like I should be able to reference the user object and not have to pass it back in but it works.

models.py

```
class Membership(models.Model):

    """Represents an active membership of a user. Both the start_date and
    end_date parameters are inclusive."""

    DEFAULT_DURATION = 365  # the default number of days a membership is active

    start_date = models.DateField(auto_created=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    membership_type = models.ForeignKey(MembershipType)
    referral = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='membership_referral', null=True)

    # Contact Info
    phone = PhoneNumberField()

    # Address Fields
    address_1 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    address_2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)

    city = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    state = USStateField()
    zip_code = USPostalCodeField()

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None,
         update_fields=None):
    """Overload the save function to set the start and end date."""
    self.start_date = datetime.date.today()
    self.end_date = (self.start_date +
                     datetime.timedelta(days=self.membership_type.period))
    super().save()

    @property
    def is_active(self):
    return self.end_date >= datetime.date.today()
```

forms.py

```
class MembershipForm(ModelForm):
    """The Form shown to users when enrolling or renewing for membership."""

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.user = kwargs.pop("user", None)

    _fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email',)
    _initial = model_to_dict(self.user, _fields) if self.user is not None else {}

    super(MembershipForm, self).__init__(initial=_initial, *args, **kwargs)
    self.fields.update(fields_for_model(User, _fields))
    self.fields['referral'].required = False

    class Meta:
    model = Membership
    fields = ['membership_type', 'referral', 'phone', 'address_1',
              'address_2', 'city', 'state']

    zip_code = USZipCodeField(max_length=5, required=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
    self.user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
    self.user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
    self.user.save()
    profile = super(MembershipForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    return profile
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def enroll(request):
    template_name = 'enroll.html'

    if request.method == 'POST':
    form = MembershipForm(request.POST, user=request.user)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('/')
    else:
    form = MembershipForm(user=request.user)

    return render(request, template_name, {'form': form})
```